# Earbuds with only 1 speaker working: will it draw less power from iPod battery?

Tags: power, batteries, headphones, ipod

I want to test battery life (music play time) for my iPod nano 6, but my earbuds has only one speaker working (other has a broken wiring). Will my test be accurate, i.e. will my earbuds draw the same amount of power from the battery as if both speakers were working? And if not, how could I mitigate/compensate this using my current earbuds, to make test resuls more accurate?

Comment: No, your results will be wrong. If you think about it ....when you are playing content there is POWER being applied to the earbuds. If one earbud is open circuit then it cannot consume power. Buy new earbuds, then run your test.

Comment: @JackCreasey, double volume won't approximate it?

Comment: No, doubling the volume is an approximate 10dB increase to the amplitude, which is a 10 (or 20) times increase in power.

Comment: You're under the assumption that the amount of power that the earbuds need is significant. **It is not.** They only need a few milliWatt and the amplifier that generates the signal will consume significantly more power (10x more power is not uncommon). The amplifier will not consume much less power when the connection to the earbud is broken. The processor that decodes the audio stream will consume even more power. My guess is that less than 1% of the power that the iPod draws from the battery actually ends up in the earbud's speakers.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The amplifiers are typically PWM and dissipate almost no power without a load.

Comment: @JackCreasey Not all are class-D / PWM, the iPod nano 6 uses a CS4207 which looks like it has an analog (non switching) headphone amplifier.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie You may be right, but the power in the earbuds will always be much more than the amplifier ...think efficiency. This might help: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/precisionhub/archive/2015/12/21/amp-up-your-cans-how-much-power-do-your-headphones-need-part-1 ...and no-one is using Class A

Comment: *but the power in the earbuds will always be much more than the amplifier* That entirely depends on the architecture of your amplifier. My small class-A amplifier here disagrees with that statement. Also, a class AB amplifier (which is probably what is used in the CS4207 which sits inside this iPod, if the amp was switched, Cirrus Logic would boast about that in the datasheet) will be class A for very small signals. Datasheet: https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/CS4207_F4.pdf

Comment: Hmm, this iPod actually uses a CLI1544C0 which has no datasheet, Google redirected me to CS4207 which might not be the same! So take above info regarding CS4207 with pinch of salt.